# Emails not sending, Cron Working

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron

I have a problem with emails not sending

I had a problem with cron yesterday 'No heartbeat task detected' and solved it by amending the cron.php file as directed by the xtento site by adding

`$isShellDisabled = true;`after `$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;`

This solved my probelm with the cron heartbeat error, but my site still isn't sending emails

can you help me solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450413/magento-1-9-1-0-order-confirmation-emails-not-sending

Comment: hi I've tied the things in the post but non work for me